# Excel 2010 VBA : error 91 at setting a workbook open with msoFileDialogOpen

Tags: excel, vba

I read here and there about FileDialogOpen and error 91 and I understand I have a variable declaration issue but can't figure what's going wrong in the code

```
Dim Ex As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim openDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim filename As String

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With openDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "Path_to_open"
    .Title = "Sélectionnez le fichier"
End With

If openDialog.Show = False Then
    MsgBox "Impossible de mettre à jour sans le fichier", vbOKOnly, "ERREUR"
    Exit Sub
End If

filename = openDialog.SelectedItems(1)
Workbooks.Open (filename)
filename = Mid(filename, 4, Len(filename) - 1)
Set wb = Ex.Workbooks.Open(filename, True, False)
```

Error 91 occurs on last line where I set wb, which i need to use later on in the code for workbook calculations. The rest of the code runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to:

`Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename, True, False)`

---

The `Set wb = Ex.Workbooks.Open(filename, True, False)` does not work, because the `Ex` is only declared, but not initialized here - `Dim Ex As Excel.Application`.

Comment: @CyrilGUICHARD - you are welcome. You are not initializing `Ex`, you are only declaring it here - `Dim Ex As Excel.Application`.

Comment: @CyrilGUICHARD - welcome. In general, you may write `Dim Ex As New Excel.Application` and give it a try with your code. I guess that it should work (but an error may always occur).